# highlighting exact phrases with solr

Tags: solr, highlighting, phrase

I am using solrj as client for indexing documents on the solr server
I am new to solr, And I am having problem with the highlighting in solr. Highlighting exact phrases with solr does not work.

For example if the keyword is: "dulce hogar" 
it returns:

```
<i> dulce </i> <i> hogar </i>
```

And it should be:

```
<i> dulce hogar </i>
```

I don't understand which is the problem.

My configuration in schema.xml

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
     <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"  />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt"   ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And in solrconfig.xml

```
 <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">

    <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
  <int name="rows">10</int>
   <str name="df">text</str>
  <bool name="hl.usePhraseHighlighter">true</bool>
</lst>


 </requestHandler>
<!-- Highlighting Component

   http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters
-->
<searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
<highlighting>
  <!-- Configure the standard fragmenter -->
  <!-- This could most likely be commented out in the "default" case -->
  <fragmenter name="gap" 
              default="true"
              class="solr.highlight.GapFragmenter">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <int name="hl.fragsize">100</int>
    </lst>
  </fragmenter>

  <!-- A regular-expression-based fragmenter 
       (for sentence extraction) 
    -->
  <fragmenter name="regex" 
              class="solr.highlight.RegexFragmenter" default="true">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <!-- slightly smaller fragsizes work better because of slop -->
      <int name="hl.fragsize">70</int>
      <!-- allow 50% slop on fragment sizes -->
      <float name="hl.regex.slop">0.5</float>
      <!-- a basic sentence pattern -->
      <str name="hl.regex.pattern">[-\w ,/\n\&quot;&apos;]{20,200}</str>
      <bool name="hl.usePhraseHighlighter">true</bool>
      <bool name="hl.highlightMultiTerm">true</bool>
    </lst>
  </fragmenter>

  <!-- Configure the standard formatter -->
  <formatter name="html" 
             default="true"
             class="solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<em>]]></str>
      <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</em>]]></str>
    </lst>
  </formatter>
```

Thanks for some help in advance,

Sil.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930180/solr-how-to-highlight-the-whole-search-phrase-only/25970452#25970452) post. You need to set hl.q="dulce hogar" field along with fastVector along with phraseHighLighter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner with solr but what I understand it's that to get the exact phrases prefer to use solr.NGramTokenizerFactory instead WhitespaceTokenizerFactory for index part only.
Or you can try the highlight option `hl.mergeContiguous=true` (see [Highlighter option](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Standard+Highlighter?bcsi-ac-95bb4efa6a1646c8=228E8A9E00000503gxxEPow1va5QngvzeE/t8AOXcW1FAAAAAwUAAA7BPgAIBwAAHQAAAH3tAAA=)) in your request. Hop it can help you.